# fixing GTID based multi source replication error on selected source

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5, gtid, multi-source

I can't find or think of a solution when ever i encounter db replication errors on affected source and repositioning the GTID in the replica.

What i do is retrieve from (four) masters gtid postion (`show master status`) then copy it to the replica server.

In replica server.

`set global gtid_slave_pos="1-10-1111111,2-20-2222222,3-30-3333333,4-40-444444"`

Is there a way to reposition the `gtid_slave_pos`only the affected source and will not cause any sync issues on other source that has no errors.

I'm using MariaDB 10.5 for master and replica.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood the question correctly, but assuming what you want is a convenient way to modify the text string in `gtid_slave_pos` so it affects only the GTID for one particular source:

I think you can write a [stored procedure](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-procedure-overview/) to do that, perhaps utilising the [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/) built-in function.

Note that you can refer to system variables in SQL statements using the `@@` prefix, e.g.:

```
SET GLOBAL gtid_slave_pos := 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(@@gtid_slave_pos, your_regexp_pattern, your_replace_str);
```

Comment: It's been a year. 
Yes, you are correct @dbdemon, I need a convenient way in the multisource replica to fix a source master that has a replication error by updating the gtid position while omitting other gtid position that is in good state.

I tried using the REGEXP_REPLACE in the SET GLOBAL gtid_slave_pos. command, It actually works.

But the only thing I did not expect is you still need to stop replication from all master sources. It will suggest stopping all replications before executing a query with REGEXP_REPLACE. Stopping a single replica will not work.